# Fortify : Android Bad Practices: Missing Google Play Services Updated Security Provider(But No Google Play Service)

Tags: android, google-play-services, fortify

Hi I already check this answer [(Fortify) Category: Android Bad Practices: Missing Google Play Services Updated Security Provider (1 Issues)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52547673/1765530) but In my APP there is no Google Play Service Added, But In Fortify It says the following error, Please see my build.gradle code below

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myworld.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue reported by Fortify is a security best practice.

When your app communicates via HTTPs you may want to be sure to run on a secure environment, and that is not true in case the installed `SecurityProvider` is out-dated, since there is the possibility to expose your app to SSL vulnerabilities (you can find a concrete example about this topic on Google Developer).

If that is your case, after adding the following dependency to your `build.gradle` file:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.3.0'
```

you can follow the article https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-gms-provider to force the update of the `SecurityProvider`, ensuring that your app is running on a secure environment.

Source: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-gms-provider

Comment: Unfortunately Fortify still shows the same error after I added `play-services-base`.